# Vlookup function using appscript returns the specified value if the data found is empty

Tags: google-apps-script

I found on internet a script allow me do Vlookup in app-script to lookup a value in other spreadsheet, but if value matching is blank it just copy "blank" cell into child spreadsheet.
I want if matching values found is blank it will write "Pending" string to cell, not just empty
please suggest me a script
thank

```js
 function getTracking() {   
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1B2yhG1dhpqgtSfF4ngqRuH51kzwQ6VwxIvCmwZZ2yQU");
  const ssh = sss.getSheetByName("Tổng Hợp");   
  const mDB = ssh.getRange(2,1,ssh.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues();    
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1slt0ExJK2X8xkRVpOzdD8NCsUmj3UeC3urfyZWsV0To");
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName("test");

  const searchValues = dsh.getRange("B2:B").getValues();   
  const matchingID = searchValues.map(searchRow => {
  const matchRow = mDB.find(r => r[0] == searchRow[0])
  return matchRow ? [matchRow [3]]: ["Không tìm thấy dữ liệu"];   
  })   
  dsh.getRange("C2:C").setValues(matchingID);   
 }
```

Comment: use an if() to test for a blank result and replace with the text you want.

Comment: Using ranges like this: `dsh.getRange("B2:B").getValues()` is a good idea in google apps script  because it generates a lot of nulls at the end of the array.  You should use `dsh.getRange("B2:B" + dsh.getLastRow()).getValues()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, by `const searchValues = dsh.getRange("B2:B").getValues();`, all rows are used. In this case, `getRange("B2:B" + dsh.getLastRow())` might be suitable.
- About `if value matching is blank it just copy "blank" cell into child spreadsheet. I want if matching values found is blank it will write "Pending" string to cell`, in this case, I would like to propose modifying `[matchRow [3]]`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```js
const searchValues = dsh.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
const matchingID = searchValues.map(searchRow => {
  const matchRow = mDB.find(r => r[0] == searchRow[0])
  return matchRow ? [matchRow[3]] : ["Không tìm thấy dữ liệu"];
})
dsh.getRange("C2:C").setValues(matchingID);
```

#### To:

```js
const range = dsh.getRange("B2:B" + dsh.getLastRow())
const searchValues = range.getValues();
const matchingID = searchValues.map(searchRow => {
  const matchRow = mDB.find(r => r[0] == searchRow[0])
  return matchRow ? [matchRow[3].toString() != "" ? matchRow[3] : "Pending"] : ["Không tìm thấy dữ liệu"];
})
range.offset(0, 1).setValues(matchingID);
```

#### Reference:

- [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: I have a quick question on this for the "return value" if there is no match, how do i force log the entered value: "return matchProjectRow ? [matchProjectRow[5]] : [searchRow[1]]" ---> The [searchRow[1]] is suppose to log the entered value (other it works but not all) but for some reason, it is taking a different value that does not even match. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @user7935276 About your question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. But, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?